# Cannot import rows from a CSV file into Talend

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend. I am trying to read a CSV file that is encoded in UTF-8. When I try to create a new file delimited, I am getting the following error.

> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

What could be causing the issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you please add the snapshot of the pipeline?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I added the screenshot above. I am trying to use it on my Mac. Is this some sort of a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a JDK/JRE library error.

In your studio, Navigate to

> Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Installed JREs

, and then select the jre1.8.0_*** from java install path.